# Swap views but maintain constraints in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, interface-builder

In Interface Builder, I have a `UIView` with a complex set of constraints attached to it. What is the best way of exchanging this `UIView` for a `UIImageView` without having to recreate all the constraints?

Deleting the `UIView` deletes its constraints too.

NB: Simply setting the `UIView`'s class to `UIImageView` won't work because it doesn't give me all the changeable attributes associated with the image view.

Comment: just an easy thought, why not add a `UIImageView` inside your `UIView`

Comment: Thanks! Would work, but makes it a little more complex than it need be. Also I was wondering if there was a general solution - eg swap a `UILabel` for a `UIButton` etc.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Infuriatingly, there is no smart answer to this. The IB simply has no ability to let you switch control types. Oh, Xcode, you do let us down.

However there is a hacky way of doing it, described by this blog: http://codenetwaves.blogspot.com.br/2012/09/change-view-to-scrollview-in-xcode.html

The steps are:

1. Right-click the storyboard, select Open As --> Source Code
2. The storyboard is an XML file. Find the view you want to change. Replace `<view ...> ... </view>` with `<imageView ...> ... </imageView>`. Don't change anything else.
3. Right-click the storyboard again, and open in Interface Builder. The views have been converted to `UIImageView`s and you can access all the normal `UIImageView` attributes.

Comment: Worked with 'pickerView' to 'datePicker' as well, or at least no problems yet. If anyone from Apple sees this, swapping out view types is a nightmare and a more "official"/less "hacky" way of doing this would be great.

Comment: This was a really really clever answer.  Unfortunately it didn't work for me: Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool failed with exit code 255

Comment: You can change "view" to "stackView" too, add an attribute `axis="vertical"` or `horizontal` to the stackView tag like `<stackView axis="vertical"` ...

Comment: It crashes Xcode when trying to change a tableView for a collectionView this way.

Comment: So. Many. Things. crash Xcode. I don't remember it ever being stable. I would suggest that this might be because table view and collection views are fundamentally incompatible - you can't just swap one for the other. (But, as every good programmer knows, Xcode still shouldn't crash anyway!)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create all constraints again manually, but I would wait with deleting the old UIView and use it for reference while copying all the constraints parameters on the new UIImageView.

Comment: Thanks. I dug around and actually did find a solution - albeit hacky. See my answer.